# How can i pass a row data from table in a html page to python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am using python flask for a web application. By using a get request (which calls rest API) I am displaying results in form of a table.(ex: each row has 'name','age','city' columns) I have provided update button to each row. Now when i click on update button that particular row fields has to be auto populated in another page where user can edit it and then update it. Now how can i get that particular row data (name,age,city) and auto populate in text fields in different page.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you immediately forwarding them to the editing page or do you want to store the info for later?

Comment: for now no need of storage. I just need to forward them to edit page immediately

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think to achieve this would be to use WTForms to populate a form on another page

So first send the info to another endpoint using your edit button

```
<input type=button onClick="location.href='example.com/edit/id123'" value='edit'>
```

and use wtforms to populate the form at the endpoint

```
from wtforms import Form
class Editform(Form):
    name = TextField('Name:', validators=[validators.required()])
    email = TextField('Age:', )
    password = TextField('City:')
    columns= TextField('Columns:')


@app.route('/edit/<id>')
def edit(id):

    # get the row that you selected
    db_data = db.getrow(id)

    # initialise and populate the form
    form = Editform()
    form.name.data = db_data .name
    form.email.data = db_data.email
    form.password.data = db_data.password
    form.column.data = db_data.column

    # this will be called when form is submitted
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # use form data to update db
        update_data = form.data
        update_db(update_data)
        flash("Successfully updated row")

    return render_template('edit.html', form=form, title='edit')
```

this isnt tested btw,  it might also be possible to do it without going to a seperate page by making the table enrties readonly text fields until you press the edit button, then you could edit the table in place and use an ajax call to update the db